# WordPress Responsive Images 4.4

Tags: wordpress, image, background, responsive, srcset

So I know WordPress has added features to optimize images through the srcset and sizes attributes, but what about background images? I like how easy it is to fit an image inside of its container if I make it a background image, but i'm worried that I might not be taking advantage of WordPress' feature this way. Is there any way to check?

Specifically, I'm talking about the actual file size, not just resizing with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that are curious, it doesn't work for background images, only actual images.

[Source Here.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/responsive-background-image-sizes?replies=6)